# Where should I place my increment?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm having a hard time figuring out where I should put my `ers++` or `ers+=1`. I've tried doing a for loop and do-while, it worked and reached the limit of 3, but it should also let the user input again and check the inputs again.

```
if (ers < 3) {
    if (a.equals(SignupPage.ee) && b.equals(SignupPage.dd) && !(a.isEmpty()) && !(b.isEmpty())) {
        System.out.println(a+"  "+b);
        tf = true;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome!", "Payment Portal", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        ElectricityPage ep = new ElectricityPage();
        ep.setVisible(true);
    } else if (a.equals("Admin") && b.equals("javaness") && !(a.isEmpty()) && !(b.isEmpty())) {
        SignupPage.aa = Admin.Fname[0];
        SignupPage.aa = Admin.Lname[0];
        ers+=1;

        ElectricityPage ep = new ElectricityPage();
        ep.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "something is wrong", "Payment Portal", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        //ers=ers+1;   
    }
    System.out.println(ers);
}
```

Comment: depends upon what you want to do ?

Comment: *"i'm having a hard time.."* ..finding the shift key? Words typed in all lower case are hard to read, like trying to listen to someone who is mumbling.  Please use an upper case letter at the start of sentences, for the word I, and proper names like `ArrayList` or Oracle.

Comment: can we see the complete do while? with exit conditions?

Comment: Basicly, you asked how to create a loop with an user-input to know if you need to continue. So this code is not usefull at all, but the input and the loop you used is